# General question on floating and non-floating objects in LaTeX

Tags: tables, floats, minipage

I am wondering when you place a non-floating object such as a `minipage` into a floating environment such as a `table` or `figure` if this construction as a whole is then a floating or a non-floating object?

Example:

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}
    ...
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}
    ...
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Is this table considered to be a floating object or in different words, is this object still floating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `minipage` environment, just like `\parbox`, `\mbox`, `\makebox` and similar commands creates an object that to LaTeX is almost like a big letter. The same holds for `tabular`.

A floating object is one that LaTeX defers the positioning of, typically `table` or `figure` (and other similar floats that can be defined with packages such as `newfloat` or are defined by packages such as `algorithm` and `listings`).

Each floating object is essentially a chunk of copy that is momentarily stored in memory for being placed accordingly to LaTeX rules. It can contain *anything* that can go in normal text, including `minipage`, `tabular` and so on. The only restriction is that a float cannot contain another float and page breaking instructions (that make no sense in them).

Let's see an example that often confuses beginners. Typically, a `figure` float has this structure

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{file}
\caption{A caption}\label{label}
\end{figure}
```

This declares a float that LaTeX will place according to its rules. However, `\includegraphics` by itself is a command similar to `\mbox` and so can go anywhere: to the eyes of LaTeX it's a "big letter". In the case of a `figure` we can see it: LaTeX builds a paragraph (with center "justification") consisting only of one big letter. The caption is, by rule, a differently built object.

Thus the answer to your question is yes: `table` is a floating object, whatever it contains.

Comment: wow, that's an amazing explanation to my simple question. thanks a lot for clarifying that. I now know even more than actually requested :-) Many thanks!