# Images in two columns in beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, two-column

I need to divide a frame into two columns and in each column i put two image taht one above the other.

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 
  \begin{document}
   \section{section1 }
   \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
   \begin{columns}
  \column{1.5in}
   \begin{figure}[!h]
   \centering
  \fbox{
   \mbox{\subfigure[Scénario 1]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]      {listefigures/scenario1.png}}\\
     \subfigure[Scénario 2]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{listefigures/sc10.png}}}}
     \caption{Image 1} 
    \end{figure}
    \column{1.5in}
     \begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
       \fbox{
     \mbox{\subfigure[Scénario 1]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{listefigures/scenario2.png}}\\
     \subfigure[Scénario 2]{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{listefigures/sc11.png}}}}
      \caption{Image 2} 
       \end{figure}
        \end{columns}
               }


         \end{document}
```

Comment: Strip Down the unneccessary packages to get a right MWE as per http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl. Is this  [Add four images on a beamer frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74903/15717) one help you ?

Comment: @texenthusiast, ok I am editing my code

Comment: You should *never* use the `figure` and `table` environments in `beamer`.  These are *floating* objects. You should just use `\includegraphics{...}` for images and `\begin{tabular}... \end{tabular}` for tables.  See [Figure in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129077),  [General question on floating and non-floating objects in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98569) and [Label and caption without float](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7210) for some discussion. (And for `beamer` you probably shouldn't use captions anyway.)

Comment: @AlanMunn, Ohhh! Then, beamer is very very very awful and I will not use it in the future. Oh my god. I am doing a bad choice. PowerPoint is very easy and very flexible against Beamerrrrrrrr!!

Comment: @phdstudent No, `beamer` is not very awful. The problem is that there are various things that you don't yet understand about LaTeX, and so you are making many (common) beginner's mistakes.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I have used latex since 2010 and I have written scientific article and so on but the beamer is the first attack and it will be the last.

Comment: I think that beamer is still limited against latex.

Comment: @phdstudent If you don't know that `figure` is a floating environment, you are still a beginner, even if you've been using LaTeX for ten years. Sorry. Yes, `beamer` takes some getting used to, but there is an excellent tutorial in the manual, and it really is quite powerful.  If you have any math at all in your presentation you surely can't be serious that Powerpoint is a better option.

Comment: @AlanMunn, for the equation, I have used beamer.But, I am using figure in beamer and it works perfectly even when I use column. But , I need to get image above the other. I did not understand what do you mean by floating. I am not going deeper in latex.

Comment: @phdstudent -- Put this command in the figure environment `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}.` You need `caption` package to do this. If you don't want the caption too then simply don't write into `\subcaptionbox{none here}`. Sorry the system thinks we are chatting so I put my answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this approach, `subcaption` package (which provides subfigure envrionment too) is used; instead of `subfigure` package.  Please note that some packages have been disable to prevent crash.

**Edit:**

1. To remove the label (a) and (b), use `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` from `caption` package.
2. To remove the `subcaption` wording, simply delete the `subcaption`.
3. To increase the vertical space between two images, use `\vskip xxpt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}  %les accents pour mac. for xelatex, pdflatex is used here
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
%\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % beamer already load this
\usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage{animate}
%  \usepackage{movie 15}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
\xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 

\begin{document}
   \section{section1}
   \begin{frame}[shrink]
   \frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
\begin{columns}
  \column{2in}
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \subcaptionbox{subcaption}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\\
 \subcaptionbox{subcaption}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
 \caption{Image 1} 
\end{figure}
  \column{2in}
\begin{figure}
\centering
 \subcaptionbox{Scénario 1}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\\
 \subcaptionbox{Scénario 2}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
 \caption{Image 2}
\end{figure}
 \end{columns}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I use subfigure and it works very well but I delete \fbox

Comment: please How can I make a vertical rule between two image in this case

Comment: I find it \vrule{}

Comment: Use \vskip 5pt. But the tolerance is limited because of the frame height. It is possible that too large dimension for skip will make them horizontally aligned.

Comment: I get en error with \vskip 5pt

Comment: How Can i change the color of the \vrule?

Comment: But my test via 'subcaptionbox' can tolerate up to 50pt.

Comment: Ok It's so nice I find it. \color{red}\vrule

Comment: Yah, simply add `\usepackage{subcaption}` at the preamble. Or replace the subfigure package name.

Comment: Yes, I see how can I change the width of \vrule ?. thanks very much

Comment: please How Can I delete the subcaption a), b),c) and so on?