# How to write a picture's source description in a `beamer` document?

Tags: beamer, includegraphics

In writing a presentation using `beamer`, and I would like to add "source information" to my graphs (under the picture). I've implemented the great solution I found here: [How to write a source description under the loaded picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58296/how-to-write-a-source-description-under-the-loaded-picture/58300#_=_) and it works fine for me on a `article` document class.

But I cannot make it work on a `beamer` document. It inserts the figure caption above and below the figure.

My code is:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Total Variance Decomposition of Grades}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Vriance decomposition}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{var_dec_eiop_explicada_FG2018}
  \caption*{Source of the image.}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

The output is:

[image: sample_graph]

Comment: Totally stealing from Alan Munn : You should never use the figure and table environments in beamer. These are floating objects. See [Figure in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129077/figure-in-beamer), [General question on floating and non-floating objects in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98569/general-question-on-floating-and-non-floating-objects-in-latex) and [Label and caption without float for some discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7210/label-and-caption-without-float). (And for beamer you probably shouldn't use captions anyway.)

Comment: @BambOo: To quote from the beamer documentation: "You can use the standard LATEX environments figure and table much the same way you would normally use
them. However, any placement specification will be ignored. Figures and tables are immediately inserted where the environments start."

Answer (score 4):

One way is use of `copyrightbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % if you like to have numbered figures
%
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}%
    {\tiny\color{gray}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Total Variance Decomposition of Grades}
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Variance decomposition}
  \copyrightbox[b]{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}%
                  {Source of the image.}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: `figure` environment in `beamer` doesn't float, so it is not need any positioning option. It also is always centered, so `\centering` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `\caption*` command you can use something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Total Variance Decomposition of Grades}
  \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \caption{Vriance decomposition}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}

  {\small Source of the image.}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```